# How to record app session duration?

Tags: objective-c, ios, timer, duration

I want to have an Game Center achievement in my application for playing my game for a certain length of time. However, I'm not sure how I would go about recording how long the user plays for. I was thinking maybe I could have a singleton class that is created in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` that is active until `applicationWillTerminate`, and in `applicationWillTerminate`, I save the duration with `NSUserDefaults`, but is this really the best way to do it (if it works at all)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application` and `-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application` to start and stop measurement.

However to measure actual gaming time you probably should implement more complex logic like start measurement on actual game start and stop it on "game over" and "pause" events. Then you could use `-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application` only to trigger "pause" automatically (which will stop measurement because it is a "pause" event).

Comment: That's helpful, but how would I actually implement the timing part?

Comment: One way is to get the current date and time at start with code like: NSDate* startDate = [NSDate date]; At stop time you call something like NSTimeInterval ti = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate]; and you have the play time in seconds. There might be other ways I guess.